# Kendo MVC Group Paging

Tags: asp.net-core, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a Kendo grid that shows around more than a million records, and in its initial load, it takes more than a minute to display.

How can I use the Kendo `GroupPaging` feature to minimize the load time so the page loads the group items on demand? Loading of the group items happens when a group is expanded. Any other options to speed up are also appreciated.

What it does, basically, is it draws the Kendo grid based on the dropdown value:

```
<div>
    @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
        .Name("samplegrid")
        .DataTextField("samplegrid")
        .DataValueField("samplegrid")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:90%" })
        .DataSource(source => source
            .Custom()
            .Transport(transport => transport
                .Read(read =>
                {
                    read.Action("infoDropdown_Read", "sample").Type(HttpVerbs.Get);
                })
            )
        )
        .Events(e =>
        {
            e.Select("onCheckSelectForDetail");
        })
    )
</div>
```

Here is the code for the grid:

```
<div>
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Portal.Data.Models.InfoModel>()
        .Name("gridSummary")
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Aggregates(aggregates =>
            {
                aggregates.Add(p => p.OutstandingCount).Sum(); 
            })
            .Group(groups =>
            {
                groups.Add(p => p.OfficeNumber);
            })
            .Batch(true)
            .ServerOperation(false)
            .Sort(sort => sort.Add(column => column.Date))
        )
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.OfficeState).Width(70).Title("xxxx");
            columns.Bound(c => c.OfficeNumber).Width(70).Title("zzzz");
            columns.Bound(c => c.OutstandingCount).Width(60).Title("yyyy");
        })
    )
</div>
```

And the controller looks like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> infoDropdown_Read()
{
    try
    {
        var infoListSR = await _eService.GetInfoListAsync();
        if (infoListSR.Failed)
        {
            Log.Error($"Unexpected error occured due to {infoListSR.ErrorData.ApplicationErrorMessage}");
            throw new DataException($"{infoListSR.ErrorData.ApplicationErrorMessage}");
        }

        return Json(infoListSR.ResultData, new JsonSerializerOptions()
        { 
            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = false
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error($"Username: {User.Identity.Name} - Dropdown list Failed with Exception: {ex}");
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An option to boost the performance, you could use the server grouping along with virtualization:

[Demo](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/server-grouppaging-virtualization)